# Are there more significantly more questions as answers?

Tags: discussion, stats

I created a couple of questions and I have a feeling that no one will answer them. There are lots of questions with no answer.

Comment: Well, the number of programs is limited, while the number of user requirements is pretty much infinite.

Comment: This is more of a feeling than anything data driven, but it does seem like only the question asking audience is really active for this particular stack exchange site. There don't appear to be a lot of people actively answering.

Answer (score 7):

Definitely not, as the [site statistics for Software Recommendations on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) show:

- 59% answered
- on average, 1.9 answers per question

But admitted, there are a lot of questions without answers:

- [2,633 questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)
- [1,088 without answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered)

Not every question is answerable, and not every request has a fitting solution. To give an extrem example (not a real question, of course): "Android web browser without internet permission" would clearly stay unanswered, as it's a contradiction in terms. Other things like [Extensions that blocks ability to click on ads](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/5665/185) are clearly niche products (if they exist at all). A few of your questions fall into the latter category at least (I e.g. have never heard of a tool to [Remux http video file on the fly](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10931/185)) – while for others I share your doubts (I'm pretty sure that e.g. a [NFS server for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4034/185) – but that's the only question I can say so for, and also the only one already having an answer. So in your case, it's clearly the "niche argument" being the cause.

Comment: If you count only questions which cannot be googled in 1 minute (to which all my current questions belong) you'll have completely different statistics.

Comment: “Never trust any statistics that you didn’t forge yourself.” / [“There are three kinds of lies: lies, damned lies, and statistics.”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics)

Comment: I think you should link here instead: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers

Comment: unfortunately, that 'answered' statistic keeps on dropping!

Comment: Reading the unanswered questions is like an invitation to start your own personal project. The questions are unanswered because the software doesn't exist (yet).

Answer (score 5):

> "Android web browser without internet permission" would clearly stay unanswered, as it's a contradiction in terms."

Shouldn't there be at least one answer here explaining the contradiction? And why such an application is not likely to ever be produced.  The question shows a lack of understanding by the person asking it, but the community can provide a service by pointing them in the right direction.  It is entirely likely that others at the same level of understanding may arrive later and also be educated.

I asked my first question on this site, not because I am unable to do the research myself, but because I don't fully understand the niche that I am exploring.  My hope by asking here, was that people who were familiar could confirm or shoot down my assumptions, give me some leads, and point me in a good direction so I have some boundaries to use when I continue my research.